# $uibModal call scope function from windowTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

I have a windowTemplate to wrap my modals into. What I'd like to achieve is to extend the wrapper with custom functionality. I added two new buttons to the wrapper a close button and a help button. The close button uses the built-in close function while the help should use my function which I added to the scope.

1: the **windowTemplate** (we put our modals into this wrapper)

```
<div modal-render="{{$isRendered}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal"
     modal-animation-class="fade"
     modal-in-class="in" ng-click="($event.target===$event.currentTarget) && close($event)"
     ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}">
  <div class="modal-dialog {{size ? 'modal-' + size : ''}}">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- This is one of the added buttons -> close -->
      <aside><a class="modal-close" ng-click="close($event)"></a></aside>
      <div class="modal-content-body" modal-transclude></div>

      <!-- this is another added item, a pager, works just great -->
      <aside class="modal-pager">#{{$parent.modalId}}</aside>

      <!-- this is the help button, won't call openHelp :( -->
      <aside class="modal-help"><a ng-click="$parent.openHelp($parent.modalId, $event)"></a></aside>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2: within a general **modalFactory**

```
    const scope = Object.assign(this.$rootScope.$new(), descriptor.scope || {}, { openHelp: this.openHelp });
    let modalInstance = this.$modal.open({
        ...props,
        ...descriptor,
        scope, // the scope here will contain the modalId and the function (openHelp) I'd like to call from the wrapper
        resolve: {
            ...params
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I can't call the function from the template. Moreover if I debug my code, I debug ui-bootstraps open method where it creates a new scope from my pushed-down scope I can call my function just fine. If I call modalOptions.$parent.openHelp() then I get the desired functionality. modalOptions is ui-bootstrap internals. $parent is needed because (in ui-bootstrap-tpls.js) `var modalScope = (modalOptions.scope || $rootScope).$new();`. Can anyone help me out with this? :)

Comment: Your way to do things seems to be too hacky. (creating scope yourself? Using $parent?), as for question - you can simply pass functions in resolve.

Comment: Sure it's hacky, but it needs to be hacky because of the inflexibility of the uibModal module :/ Mind that this isn't a modal template where we can pass functions with resolve. It's the windowTemplate which is a way in uibModal to override the de-facto modal wrapper with ours. There's not to much possibility to pass variables/functions there :(

Comment: cant you add this button to modal template?

Comment: Nope, there are too much modals for adding them for each.. But see my answer below

Comment: You can add for all at once. If u interested, I can show how.

Answer (score 0):

### Answering my own question

Blah.. -.- I found out why this wasn't working. So TL;DR

`<aside class="modal-help"><a ng-click="$parent.openHelp($parent.modalId, $event)"></a></aside>`

line was the reason. More precisely I attached style rules to the *modal-help* class and because I accidentally put the class on the *aside* tag not on the *anchor* tag the anchor had no dimensions (no width, no height, no value) so I suspect that when I was clicking on the icon the event's target was the aside tag and it bubbled up from there on. Basically I was never clicking on the anchor tag with the click handler. Sigh'. Just place the *modal-help* class on the *a* tag.

Meanwhile, I was coming up with an alternative solution which is still too hacky :D

- Add a "data-modal-identifier" attribute to the most outer container on the wrapper, assign e.g `{{$parent.modalId}}` value to it, just to make sure you will be able to query for it.
- In the factory subscribe to the rendered event of the instance `modalInstance.rendered.then(...)`
- When the modal was rendered search for the DOM elem of the wrapper: `` document.querySelector(`div[data-modal-identifier="${scope.modalId}]"`); ``
- With event delegation subscribe for the click event and call the openHelp func if the event source was our help icon.